# Один favico для всего сайта

Tags: html, icon

Помогите пожалуйста, мне надо чтоб не вставлять на каждую страницу иконку, а просто поставить тегу. У меня вот такой код, и не работает!

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Comment: **минусую**

Comment: @Саша Осипов

>а просто поставить тегу

это как?

Comment: видешь стоит две теги? <head></head> это вроде теги чтоб на каждом сайте была одни иконка

Comment: ну тогда изменю вопрос, какую надо поставить тегу или скрипт чтоб на каждой странице была одна и таже иконка, чтоб не надо было савить один и тот же скрипт на каждой странице сайта

Comment: Тогда положите в корневой каталог сайта (если у вас Apache) и укажите в конфиге

Comment: Вот [например](http://www.google.co.uz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGcQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cyberforum.ru%2Fapache%2Fthread307514.html&ei=tuz_T9PIJoW7hAfsgpXzBw&usg=AFQjCNHvTKBpsE9J3Lz5U4FgWxqGk08mzg "Один favicon для всех страниц сайта") посмотрите UPD в моём ответе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Саша Осипов](/users/8079/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/8079/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2), вы, по моему не понимаете даже основ HTML:

1  Обязательная структура страницы HTML такова:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
     ..Не отображаемые теги..
    </head>
    <body>
    .. Отображаемые теги ..
    <body>
</html>
```

2 В раздел `<head>` помещаются теги  (например meata) которые влияют на обработку страницы, но не на её содержимое (например кодировку страницы её стили), например:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Заголовок страницы</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">                   
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
       Параграф
      <p>
    <body>
</html>
```

***P.S***
Почитайте [здесь](http://www.htmlbook.ru)

***UPD***:
Я понял чего вы хотите. Если у вас Apache то погуглите [favicon в Apache](https://www.google.co.uz/search?q=favicon+%D0%B2+Apache&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Rules, сама только фраза *`Обязательная структура страницы HTML `* — не корректна. По спецификации `html5` такие теги, как `head` и `body`, являются необязательными. Полный список можно посмотреть [http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission](здесь).

Comment: @Crasher спасибо за просвещение :)

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это html, и по этому для каждой страницы нужно вставлять эту же иконку.

Comment: Не согласен, на Apache можно...

Comment: это ты мне или ТС-су?

Comment: @johniek_comp - Вам

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта:

1) Уберите этот тег вообще, а файл favicon.ico перенесите в корень сайта, все браузеры по дефолту ищут favicon в корневой папке.

2) В теге, там где путь к файлу, перед images добавьте слеш, сейчас favicon.ico у вас ищется не от корня, а от текущего раздела. Тобишь, к примеру, на страничке http://site.ru/ браузер ищет иконку в http://site.ru/images/favicon.ico а на внутренней страничке типа http://site.ru/articles/ иконка ищется уже по пути http://site.ru/articles/images/favicon.ico