# Как добавить фавикон к сайту?

Tags: html

Как прикрутить фавикон к сайту?
А так же каких размеров должен быть максимальный фавикон?
И чем конвертировать в ico?

Comment: ***Перенесено из комментария*** [Похожий вопрос уже был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126927/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-favico-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0 "Один favico для всего сайта").@Krezvaa, когда набираете заголовок вопроса, обращайте внимание на выпадающий список уже заданных вопросов!

Answer (score 6):

гугл в помощь как говорится... просто вбил первое ваше предложение и вот, например, первые 4-е ссылки:

1. [первая ссылка](http://gggg.com.ua/?p=324)
2. [вторая ссылка](http://hochuwebsite.ru/view_post/Kak-ustanovit-favicon-na-sajt)
3. [третья ссылка](http://pervushin.com/favicon-ico-create-install-blog.html)
4. [четвертая ссылка](http://blog-raskruti.ru/vse-o-wordpress/kak-sozdat-favikon-dlya-sayta)

думаю хватит и первых двух.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается очень просто в секции head:

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="путь_к_иконке" />
</head>
```

Можно юзать PNG, но лучше все-таки ICO. Качество выше будет.

Comment: По-мойму качество у PNG лучше. А вообще давайте вспомним IE и оставим ICO =)

Answer (score 2):

> Остается сделать желаемую иконку 16х16 пикселов и сохранить ее под
>   именем favicon.ico в корне сайта. Браузер автоматически ищет этот файл
>   и добавляет его в адресную строку, а также закладки.
>
> Файл не обязательно должен располагаться в корне сайта, но тогда
>   следует указать браузеру, где он находится. Это делается через тег
>   , как показано ниже.
>
> Атрибут href задает расположение и имя файла.
>
> Формат рисунка не обязательно должен быть ICO, также допускается
>   использование GIF и PNG. При этом необходимо сменить значение атрибута
>   type на image/gif или image/png, в зависимости от типа изображения.
>
> ```
> <head>  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/png"> </head>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то достаточно взять картинку .png например 24х24 , поменять расширение на .ico и положить в корень сайта

Answer (score -1):

в корень сайта скинь файл с именем favicon.ico